# Is there an event that occurs after data-rel='back'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, back

I'm trying to compare the `window.location.hash` after a user has gone back a page using a button with `data-rel='back'`.

Is there an event which occurs at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/navigation/

```
// Respond to back/forward navigation
$(window).on("navigate", function(event, data) {
    if (data.state.direction == "back") {
        alert("User navigated back.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, the same events are fired as if you would click a button without `data-rel="back"`.

I assume you are changing a page container. Then it's here:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/

The events are at least:

- beforechange (old page)
- beforehide (old page)
- beforetransition (new page)
- beforeshow (new page)
- change (new page)

This skeleton is in the case the new page was already loaded and created. If not, there are even more events.